# Scientific terms for front-brain, mid-brain and back-brain

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, brain, anatomy

I am looking for a (semi-) scientific way of phrasing "front part of brain" (part 1), "middle part of brain" (part 2) and "back part of brain" (part 3) as denoted in the attached picture.
I would (VERY!) loosely define these parts as:

- front: everything in front of the ventricles
- mid: approximately at the same height as the ventricles
- back: behind the ventricles

I need this to qualitatively describe some results I have.

[image: front_mid_back]

Note that this is different than forebrain, midbrain and hindbrain (which is the main result that google comes up with when searching for this).

(edit) Additional context: I have a method that selects a certain background volume in the brain. These background volumes are then used to make a segmentation. The placement of these background volumes seems to correlate with whether or not the segmentation is "good" or "bad". "Good" segmentations seem to correlate with backgrounds placed in the "mid-brain". "Bad" segmentations seem to correlate with background volumes places elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome. What's the context of the terms? I mean, what do you wish to explain? Chances are big there are no established anatomical terms for what you wish to describe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are working with 3D data, why not segment them into lobes? You have 4: **frontal** (front), **occipital** (back), **temporal** (lateral middle) and **parietal** (top middle) lobes. If you *really* must have three only, group the middle two together.

[image: Brain lobes and topographical borders]

You have **sulci** (singular: sulcus) as references which you can naturally use as topographical borders for segmentation.

You can also define your own regions, provided that they are universal. I see no reason why not to define your own regions. You can define the arm as ending at the wrist, or including the hand. It's all semantic, and what matters most is to be clear with your definitions, not inflexibly adhering to preconception. You can use any gyrus or sulcus to define your arbitrary areas, pick however you like, with the knowledge that it must be suitable across all your samples and not confound your data in the end:

[image]

Comment: thanks, this helps. I decided to do it based on lobe/part of lateral ventricle it is adjacent to.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer**

1. Anteroventricular coronal segment
2. Paraventricular coronal segment
3. Posteroventricular coronal segment

**Long Answer**

As indicated by @AliceD in the [comments](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/109115/scientific-terms-for-front-brain-mid-brain-and-back-brain#comment199999_109115), I'm not sure there are technical terms to describe these regions *per se*.

- Of greatest issue is how imprecise you're describing their cutoffs. Without citing very specific brain region/anatomy demarcations, any chance for proper technical vocabulary is minimal. (even broad [brain divisions](https://web.archive.org/web/20210518002930/http://vanat.cvm.umn.edu/neurLab3/divisions.html) have defined boundaries)

Although something specific/technical is not really appropriate given your imprecise approach, I think some sort of general regional approach could be adopted:

So, what you have drawn are three mostly arbitrary [coronal](https://faculty.washington.edu/chudler/slice.html) segments of the brain (i.e., three regions divided by 2 frontal planes).

[image]

You could simply refer to them as the **anterior, posterior, and middle coronal sections or segments**.

Or, I suppose you could also say **pre-ventricular, ventricular, and post-ventricular coronal segments** to place them in the context of the ventricles.

- Though, perhaps you could create even more precise [affixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affix) terms: **anteroventricular, periventricular, and posteroventricular** coronal sections.

  - though, perhaps [**paraventricular**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paraventricular) could also be used vs [periventricular](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/periventricular), since your middle segment extends beyond the immediate perimeter of the ventricles.

<sup>Again, the above is stated based solely on a broad application of these generalized affixable terms. I am not commenting on their appropriateness or possible conflict with any current usage of any of these terms to perhaps clinically refer to more specified regions.</sup>